# Typeahead.js change cursor to pointer on hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I am failing to get the cursor to change to `pointer` when hovering over `typeahead` suggestions.

I tried applying the cursor style in several `typeahead.css` classes, does not seem to work.

My `typeahead.js` version is `0.10.5`.

Below is my `typeahead.css` file:

```
*
 * typehead.js-bootstrap3.less
 * @version 0.2.1
 * https://github.com/hyspace/typeahead.js-bootstrap3.less
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */
.input-group {
  width: 100%;
}
.has-warning .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
.has-warning .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  border-color: #8a6d3b;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.has-warning .twitter-typeahead .tt-input:focus,
.has-warning .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint:focus {
  border-color: #66512c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #c0a16b;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #c0a16b;
}
.has-error .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
.has-error .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  border-color: #a94442;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.has-error .twitter-typeahead .tt-input:focus,
.has-error .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint:focus {
  border-color: #843534;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #ce8483;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #ce8483;
}
.has-success .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
.has-success .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  border-color: #3c763d;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.has-success .twitter-typeahead .tt-input:focus,
.has-success .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint:focus {
  border-color: #2b542c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #67b168;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #67b168;
}
.input-group .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-input,
.input-group .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-hint {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}
.input-group .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-input,
.input-group .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-hint {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
select.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
select.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
textarea.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
textarea.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint,
select[multiple].input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
select[multiple].input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  height: auto;
}
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) .tt-hint {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-hint {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-hint {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  height: 46px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
select.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
select.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  height: 46px;
  line-height: 46px;
}
textarea.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
textarea.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint,
select[multiple].input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
select[multiple].input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  height: auto;
}
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) .tt-hint {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-hint {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-hint {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
.twitter-typeahead {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.input-group .twitter-typeahead {
  display: table-cell !important;
}
.twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  color: #999999;
}
.twitter-typeahead .tt-input {
  z-index: 2;
}
.twitter-typeahead .tt-input[disabled],
.twitter-typeahead .tt-input[readonly],
fieldset[disabled] .twitter-typeahead .tt-input {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: #eeeeee !important;
}
#scrollable-dropdown-menu .tt-dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.tt-dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  min-width: 160px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  *border-right-width: 2px;
  *border-bottom-width: 2px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu .tt-suggestion {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333333;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #262626;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor a {
  color: #262626;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu .tt-suggestion p {
  margin: 0;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor,
.tt-suggestion:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.tt-suggestion:hover { /* UPDATE: newer versions use .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor */
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0097cf;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Anyone have any ideas where the problem is coming from?

Comment: What browser are you in, what cursor do you see, and is it working correctly when you view https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ ?

Comment: I am using firefox. I tried the link using firefox and it did work correctly. Also i just tried to run my project in chrome, the cursor is displayed correctly

Comment: @TimOgilvy thank you for suggesting to try the link. I checked the css used `.tt-suggestion:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;
}

.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;

}` This has sorted out the problem. So please go ahead and add your answer so i can mark it correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.tt-suggestion:hover { 
  cursor: pointer; 
  color: #fff; 
  background-color: #0097cf; 
} 
.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor { 
  color: #fff; 
  background-color: #0097cf; 
}
```